# simultaneous usage of bot = discord.Client(intents = intents) and bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

> I am trying to incorporate the `on_member_join` event along with some other commands such as `kick` and `ban.`

The issue is that due to changes, in order to use `on_member_join` I have to add:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True

bot = discord.Client(intents = intents)
```

to my code in order for it to function properly. The issue is that I am not able to declare  `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')` -- this as a result does not allow me to use my command methods (i.e. `kick` and `ban`). Is there any workaround?

Apart from the aforementioned issue, there are two more:

**1)** When using the declaration `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')`, my two commands, `kick` and `ban`, do not work through typing `!kick @Name` / `!ban @Name`. Some notes here: 1) the bot has access to all the channels, 2) the bot has permissions to both kick and ban, 3) the **only** way that these commands work is when I include in my code `await kick(f'<@{message.author.id}', message.author)` / `await ban(f'<@{message.author.id}>', message.author)`.

**2)** When using the declarations

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True

bot = discord.Client(intents = intents)
```

**ONLY** the event `on_member_join` works properly. The event `on_member_leave` does **NOT** work at all. What can I do?

Full code:

```py
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = discord.Client(intents = intents)
#bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')


'''@bot.command()           
async def kick(message, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    await bot.get_channel(805839858887032832).send(f'<@{member.id}> has been kicked!')

@bot.command()
async def ban(message, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    await bot.get_channel(805839858887032832).send(f'<@{member.id}> has been banned!')'''

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {.user}".format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await bot.get_channel(805839858887032832).send(f'<@{member.id}> has joined the server!')
    await member.send(f'Welcome to {bot.get_guild(GUILDID)}!')

# not working
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    await bot.get_channel(805839858887032832).send(f'<@{member.id}> left the server!')
    await member.send(f'Say bye to {bot.get_guild(GUILDID)}!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return      

    '''if message.author.id == AUTHORID:
        await kick(f'<@{message.author.id}>', message.author)'''


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Notes on the aforementioned code: in the place of `GUILDID`, `AUTHORID`, `TOKEN`, the original code has realistic values, but for privacy reasons they have been censored in that way.

Comment: why would you want to use both things? commands.Bot has all the functionality that discord.Client has, means it also supports all events, also your ban and kick commands as well as the on_member_* events don’t work cause you didn’t pass the intents into the bot constructor, you passed them in the client but not the bot, there’s also no such thing as the on_member_leave event, it’s on_member_remove.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Even when I pass the intents, only the `on_member_join` event works. The other event yields no output. How can I use `commands.Bot` for the `on_member_join` and `on_member_remove` events?

Comment: There's no "secret way" of using those events, try printing something in the `on_member_remove` event,  if there's still no output you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

`commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')` is nothing but a subclass on `discord.Client(intents = intents)`, all functions a client can do, a bot can do too. If you look in the source of `discord.py` you'll find that the class `commands.Bot` is made like:

```
class Bot(BotBase, discord.Client):
    pass
```

Hence your bot will also get all the events your Client would get, as it is a Client subclass.

To add the intents to your bot, simple add `intents=intents` to your `commands.Bot` creation like:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = intents)
```